# Recursive parse in Red

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I want to parse-skip Forth-style if's from input, Forth-style means each if starts with `if` and ends with `then`, assuming all input is correct handling of mismatches is not required.

The problem is each part of `if` can recursively contain any number of other `if`'s.

Here is my best solution with test cases:

```
Red []

skip-nested-ifs: [skip to ['if | 'then] skip-nested-ifs-helper]
skip-nested-ifs-helper: ['then | skip-nested-ifs skip-nested-ifs-helper ]


rules: skip-nested-ifs

test-cases: [
   [if a then]
   [if a else b then]
   [if a if b then then]
   [if a if b then 5 then]
   [if a if b then 5 if c then then]
   [if a else if b then then]
   [if a else if b then 5 then]
   [if a else if b then if c then then]
   [if a if b if c then if d then then then]
]

forall test-cases [
   prin [mold test-cases/1 ""]
   print either parse test-cases/1 rules [ "OK" ] [ "FAIL" ]
]
```

The output is:

```
[if a then] OK
[if a else b then] OK
[if a if b then then] OK
[if a if b then 5 then] FAIL
[if a if b then 5 if c then then] FAIL
[if a else if b then then] OK
[if a else if b then 5 then] FAIL
[if a else if b then if c then then] OK
[if a if b if c then if d then then then] OK
```

So three of them fail because they contain something (`5` in this case) between one `then` and another.

Probably the fix is very simple and obvious, but I don't see it right now. Could you help me to fix rule above if possible or show a different one which passes all tests?

Comment: Is your use of `to` in the first rule intended, or did you really want `thru` rather?

Comment: `parse-trace` is useful to debug parse

Comment: @DocKimbel I'm using `to` intentionally to match `then` after, because if `then` found first - this means current `if` is finished, otherwise we hit nested one.

Comment: @user3033648 I just wanted to check that you were aware that `to` is not consuming the argument rule, just stopping *before* it (`['if | 'then]` in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if your rule is fixable or not, as it heavily relies on recursion, but fails to provide iteration support which is needed for test #5. I was not able to fix it, as `skip` is used to consume both terminal and non-terminal tokens (including `if`), so it makes it hard for me to follow.

I came up with a different solution. It is longer, but passes all your tests (using Red):

```
rules: [
    'if skip 
    opt ['else [some rules | skip]]
    opt some rules
    'then
    opt [some rules | ahead 'then | skip]
]
```

Notes:

- I tried to make the grammar rules as explicit as possible.
- Notice the usage of `some` to iteratively consume the sub-expressions.
- The `ahead 'then` guarding rule, is there to prevent `skip` from consuming an extra `then` which would be part of a parent expression (in case of a recursive invocation).
- It uses `skip` to pass over the terminal value following `then` or `else`, though it is not clear from your description if there can be more than one value there. Anyway, it is easy to extend for matching more complex patterns if needed.

If you want to use such rule for skipping input, you can then invoke it like this:

```
skip-ifs: [to 'if rules]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the last item in rules: `opt [some rules | ahead 'then | skip]` also skips next `if` if there is one right after current, like here: `[if a then if c then]`. I want to skip only one current if, the next one will be handled separately. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Just replace `ahead 'then` with `ahead ['if | 'then]` and it will parse correctly also such different pattern.

Comment: I tried `opt [some rules | ahead ['if 'then] | skip]` as last part of rule and it fails half of the tests